# Issue with clickhouse equality comparison between integers

Tags: database, statistics, clickhouse

I have a Clickhouse database where I store my data for analytics. In the table I have a column with name Date which is of type Int64. I store dates in this format (202403011) representing 2023-03-11. Im trying to check if date is equal to a specific date like this :

```
select *
from Statistics FINAL
WHERE Date = 20240311;
```

But I am receiving this error : *Code: 42. DB::Exception: Number of arguments for function toDateOrNull doesn't match: passed 2, should be 1. Second argument makes sense only for DateTime and Decimal. (NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS_DOESNT_MATCH) (version 24.2.1.2248 (official build))*

I have tried different things but the only this that has worked was converting the date column to string then to date and then compare it with the date like this `toDate(toString(Date)) = '20240311'`

I tried the equal() function that is offered by Clickhouse I got the same problem. It is interesting cause using different comparisions like >, <, >=, <=, the comparison works perfectly. But only using the equal comparer it throws me that error

Comment: Please provide a link with some reproducible example returning this error like [this](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/b9df90b6-0840-4aa4-be0e-e2a4c8aba55a) one.

Comment: Date is usually Int32, to @MarkBarinstein point a reproducible example would help. Are you using an Int64 as the actual data type? That format will not be converted at insert time automatically i.e.
```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    `d` DateTime
) ENGINE = Memory

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('2024-03-11'), ('20240311')

SELECT *
FROM t


┌───────────────────d─┐
│ 2024-03-11 00:00:00 │
│ 1970-08-23 07:18:31 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Comment: There must be some details that trigger the error. tried and just defining a table as int64 named Date would not cause the error above.

```
CREATE TABLE example_table
(
    `Date` Int64,
    `name` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY Date; SELECT *
FROM example_table
WHERE Date = 20230101

Query id: 10931758-6cbb-4f12-94ba-a96dc09297f8

┌─────Date─┬─name──┐
│ 20230101 │ Alice │
└──────────┴───────┘
```